# mahout taste: in-memory DataModel that supports set/removePreference

Tags: mahout, recommendation-engine

I could not find an in-memory DataModel that supports setPreference / removePreference / refresh. Instead, they all "recreate" a new GenericDataModel anytime one adds or remove preferences. Am I missing something? Shall I build my own?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't missing anything; they generally don't support this operation. I suppose the overall idea is that changing data means recomputing a lot of other things and so should happen via bulk reloads of some underlying data source.

Comment: Thanks Sean. I added a patch to JIRA with my implementation. Seed https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAHOUT-1050